# Chrome Browser debugger comes back with jQuery statements as being "undefined functions"

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, function, element

I have code below that does work.  It makes the .ajax call to my php file, retrieves the array of data as required.

However, when I start looping through the array, I am attempting to dynamically create DOM elements within an existing table.  At the point of these function calls, I get the error "undefined functions", note that that commented out alerts DO work, so I know that data is being returned, and the loop IS being entered.  I just cannot figure out why my syntax to create the dom elements and attributes is not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
                    <script type="text/javascript"> 
                        $.ajaxSetup({
                            cache: false
                        });
                         $(document).ready(
                        function(){
                            $.ajax({
                                url: "PHPLibrary/selectMemberResults.php",
                                type: "POST",
                                dataType: "json",
                                success: function (data) { 
                                    //alert("1 Total number of rows of data >" + data.length + "<"); 
                                        for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
                                            //alert("2 Total number of rows of data >" + data[i].length + "<");
                                            $memName = data[i][0];
                                            $busName = data[i][1];  
                                            //alert($memName);  
                                            //alert($busName); 
                                            (function ($) {
                                            $('tr').attr({width:"100%",id:"row"}).appendto('#memberResults');  
                                            $('td').text($memName).appendto("row");
                                            $('tr').attr({width:"100%",id:"row"}).appendto('#memberResults');  
                                            $('td').text($busName).appendto("row");
                                            }(jQuery)); 
                                }
                            });
                        }); 
                    </script>
```

One final note, I've gone through and checked that all curly braces and brackets have matching pairs, in the correct order, as do all of the parenthesis which are terminated with a semicolon (;).

Any thoughts or help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!!!!

Comment: `$('tr')` will select every `<tr>` currently on the page.  `$('<tr/>')` will create a new element.

Comment: Also, `appendto` -> `appendTo`

Comment: And element id's must be unique (`row` gets duplicated).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to create elements your syntax is incorrect; currently you are selecting elements. For example this code:

```
$('tr').attr({ width: "100%", id: "row" }).appendTo('#memberResults');
```

Is selecting *all* `tr` elements in the page and appending them to `#memberResults`. Instead you need to use this syntax:

```
$('<tr />').attr({ width: "100%", id: "row"}).appendTo('#memberResults');
```

Note the HTML-like angle brackets in the selector. You can also use the second parameter of the jQuery object to apply the needed attributes to the new element, so your final code becomes:

```
$('<tr />', { width: "100%", id: "row" }).appendTo('#memberResults');
```

Finally, it should be `appendTo()` not `appendto()`, and also be careful you don't duplicate `id` attributes with your appended elements. I would suggest using a class on them instead.

Comment: Great input guys, thanks!  Now, with regards to appending to the table row with the id of ROW....how can I make that dynamic, as this is all the result of rows being of data being pulled out of the database....for instance, I'd like to dynamically call it "row1", then the next "row2", etc, etc.....Should I just do it with a variable and then put the variable in where I am declaring the ID of the parent to appendTo ?

Comment: I would just use a single class. Having incremental ids always becomes a maintenance nightmare. If you need some way of identifying the row, add the DB id as a data attribute which you can grab on click.